# My local host isn't working.What should i do?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, react-router, localhost, react-bootstrap

I am building a restaurant website with Reactjs. It was going well suddenly I got this error message from localhost. Whenever I am running "npm start" the browser is showing this error instead of displaying my website. The error message is page unresponsive & out of memory. 
So, what should I do now to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.[image: localhost isn't responsive and showing error message]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to find an infinite loop,
maybe you have nested route to the same route or something like that.

Comment: Yes it generally happen when the app enters an infinite loop. So it just stalls you for rendering and then throws that error.